# How to say "with Person A and Person B"?

Tags: particles, particle-と

Recently I saw this sentence:

> マリアさんもホセさん、テレサちゃんときてください

I understand this as

> Maria, please also come, along with Jose and Teresa

If my translation is correct, is the comma a standard way of including multiple other people? How about using と instead?

> ホセさんとテレサちゃんと

As a side question, if we replace も with は, how does the meaning change? Would it be

> Maria, please come, along with Jose and Teresa

without the "also" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can use と in this sentence such as マリアさんもホセさんとテレサちゃんときてください. Either is fine.

If some words are listed, と is often omitted such as 明日学校に、教科書、鉛筆、ノート、絵の具、お弁当、体操着を持ってきてください.

You can replace も with は, and that means as you said.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, Maria and Jose are being addressed and asked to come with Teresa.
If you think this way, the comma will make more sense.

Maria and Jose, please come along with Teresa.

は won't make any sense here, because it functions as a being verb as is/are.

Hope it helps!